# How to properly set multiple states in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently learning React/hooks/redux.  To do so, I'm building a react app that takes in data from a climate API.

The problem I'm having is correctly setting state for a couple of items in useEffect.  One state relies on the other, so I'm trying to figure out how to properly call useEffect so I don't get infinite loops and follow best-practices.

A little background before the code included below:

-The user creates a project, and selects a city.  This produces a cityId that I'm storing in my "project" state.

-On the user's dashboard, they can click a project that sends the project ID in a queryString to my ClimateData component.

-ClimateData passes the project ID queryString to the "getProjectByID" redux action to get the project state, including it's cityId.

-ClimateData includes the IndicatorList component, which brings in a list of all the climate data breakouts.  I want the user to click one of these list items and have ClimateData's "indicatorByCityData" state set.  So I passed ClimateData's setState function to IndicatorList and have the list call with onClicks. ***Is there a better way I should do this?***

-On ClimateData, once I have the project's cityId, and the selected item from IndicatorList, I need to call "getIndicatorByCity" and pass both the cityId and indicator to have the result saved in the "indicatorByCityData" state

I keep trying to change how my ClimateData's useEffect is written, but I'm either getting infinite loops or errors.  How can I best change this to set both states and follow best practices?

The redux actions and reducers have been tested elsewhere and work fine, so for brevity, I'll exclude them here and just focus on my ClimateData and IndicatorList components:

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import IndicatorList from './IndicatorList';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import { getProjectById } from '../../actions/projects';
import { getIndicatorByCity } from '../../actions/climate';

const ClimateData = ({
  getProjectById,
  getIndicatorByCity,
  project: { project, loading },
  auth,
  match
}) => {
  const [indicatorByCityData, setIndicatorByCityData] = useState({});

  const nullProject = !project;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!project) getProjectById(match.params.id);

    // Once we have the cityID, set the indicatorByCityData state, with a default selected Indicator
    if (!loading) setIndicatorByCityData(getIndicatorByCity(project.cityId));
  }, []);

  // Get the selected indicator from IndicatorList and update the indicatorByCityData state
  const setIndicator = indicator => {
    setIndicatorByCityData(getIndicatorByCity(project.cityId, null, indicator));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {project === null || loading || !indicatorByCityData ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <Link to='/dashboard' className='btn btn-light'>
            Back To Dashboard
          </Link>

          <h1 className='large text-primary'>{`Climate Data for ${project.city}`}</h1>
          <IndicatorList setIndicator={setIndicator} />
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ClimateData.propTypes = {
  getProjectById: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getIndicatorByCity: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  project: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  project: state.projects,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProjectById, getIndicatorByCity })(
  ClimateData
);

/******************************************************************/

import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import { getIndicatorList } from '../../actions/climate';

const IndicatorList = ({
  getIndicatorList,
  auth: { user },
  climateList: { indicatorList, loading },
  setIndicator
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getIndicatorList();
  }, [getIndicatorList]);

  return loading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      {indicatorList.length > 0 ? (
        <Fragment>
          <ul>
            {indicatorList.map(indicator => (
              <li key={indicator.name}>
                <a href='#!' onClick={() => setIndicator(indicator.name)}>
                  {indicator.label}
                </a>
                <br />- {indicator.description}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </Fragment>
      ) : (
        <h4>No climate indicators loaded</h4>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

IndicatorList.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  climateList: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  setIndicator: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  climateList: state.climate
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getIndicatorList })(IndicatorList);
```

Comment: To be honest, I read this 5 times and still can't really understand the issue. It might give you more answers if you try to boil down the actual issue so that only necessary information is required. But one thing I did get: You are passing the state update function to a child, and wondered if this is okay. I do this all the time. Allowing children to update the state of the parent is not bad practice.

Comment: Just a side note: Redux now has hooks, meaning that you don't really need to use the (in my opinion) really ugly connect() HOC. Hooks are much prettier! https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Comment: @ViktorW While I don't *disagree* that hooks are prettier, I dislike the way the redux hooks become implementation details. The `connect` HOC allows one to design a state management agnostic presentational component API and `connect` is merely connecting external data to the props API of the component. Makes for super simple unit testing, just mock the props versus mocking an entire redux system. Granted, this is simply just *my opinion*, but thought it prudent to share why sometimes hooks may not always be the best solution.

Comment: @ViktorW The issue I'm having is determining how to use ClimateData's useEffect to 1) get the project.cityID from redux state, and then 2) pass that cityId and the user selected indicator (from child component IndicatorList) to setIndicatorByCityData().  Thanks for the tip regarding redux hooks, I'll look into it!